# Normal map baking / strange shading

Tags: baking

Why I am getting such strange result after baking?

I baked a cube with bevels onto simple cube. When I then connect the normal map (which looks ok and does not contain any checkers on flat surfaces) the shading looks strange with a checkerboard pattern on the surface.

[image]

[image]

[file](http://pasteall.org/blend/59c402c19d2a42be82dd4796be844818)

Comment: hello, maybe show your Shade Editor and your UV Editor, or even pack the image and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The squares can happen when you have the high-poly cube shaded smooth and the low-poly shaded flat and then bake the normal.

Comment: We want a file.  But I wonder, are you subdividing the mesh?  Don't subdivide the mesh unless you baked with it subdivided.  And if you baked with it subdivided, use the same subdivision you baked with.

Comment: Here is the file. I test all I can but it is still same result. https://pasteall.org/blend/59c402c19d2a42be82dd4796be844818

Comment: Both are shaded smooth. Both with Autosmooth on (I think that this is doing something wrong with lowpoly). But without autosmooth the final result looks not as it should on flat faces. This should be simple and predictable.

Comment: I test it million times wit different options and I think it is something with autosmooth setting on lowpoly. It is not logical for me. I thought that auto smooth adds automatically sharp edges to and object depending on angle so it is ok for low poly to use it.